# Boolean default value in JsonFormatter web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a problem in setting default value of boolean in web api.

I have the following implementation

Model

```
public class StatusModel 
{
  [Range(1, long.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Id is invalid or is not sent.")]
  [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9'' ']+$", ErrorMessage = "Special character should not be entered")]
   public long Id { get; set; }

   [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "IsActive is invalid or is not sent.")]
   [Range(0 , 1 , ErrorMessage="IsActive Is Sent In Value 0 or 1 Only")]
   public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPut]
public string Activate([FromBody] StatusModel model)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
```

json formatter in `WebApi.Config`

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // To register exception logger of IQueryable exceptions
        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new TraceExceptionLogger());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // JSON
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        //to convert date time to local
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        // JSON formatter
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }
}
```

The problem is each time i am trying to send boolean to my service the value is confusing for example

1. If i send the following Json `Is Active` value is set to `true`

   {
     "Id": 4,
     "IsActive":5
     }
2. If i send the following Json the following error appears `IsActive is invalid or is not sent` which is correct

   {
   "Id": 4,
   "IsActive":"0"
   }

Comment: is it not possible to just send `"IsActive": true` or `false`?

Comment: its possible but i am implementing a web service so i am validating the input send to api

Comment: I would expect a bool to receive bool values not numbers though... I don't know if it's supposed to work with numbers, but I wouldn't expect it to

Comment: if i send `true` , `false` , `1` or `0` the service works fine but i am doing extra validation in the input 
so if i send any integer `greaer than 1` so `IsActive is set to true`

Comment: sorry I'm confused now; what is the problem?

Comment: if i send any integer `greater than 1` so `IsActive is set to true` while this is not a valid boolean for example if i send `IsActive = 6` this should be considered as not valid boolean not true value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115717/discussion-between-mohamed-salah-and-the-bearded-llama).